# How to properly rewrite a friendly URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like `index.php?url_id=u5531e3aas01fe5c2` and I also want to make it work like `/u5531e3aas01fe5c2`, that it to pass a parameter to my PHP, but something is wrong with my code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /try/
RewriteRule /u[a-z0-9]{17} /index.php?url_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

P.S.
And also is it possible to rewrite URL that if appears `index.php?url_id=u5531e3aas01fe5c2`, it would be rewritten to `/u5531e3aas01fe5c2`

Comment: /u5531e3aas01fe5c2 is indeed a very friendly URL :)

Comment: @darma 5531e3aas01fe5c2 is user id, u just a prefix.

Comment: I don't see anything glaring. `RewriteBase` can complicate things. Be sure you understand how it works.

Comment: you are missing capturing parenthesis `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^u([a-z0-9]{16}) /index.php?url_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: welcome, but it was also 16 not 17. because 'u' doesn't count, it's out of regex scope ...